# Quantlib's --enable-indexed-coupons flag

Tags: quantlib

When building Quantlib from source there used to be an --enable-indexed-coupons flag option. This was an override for the default 'par coupon' setting which came with the standard Quantlib installation at the time. Has this flag been deprecated in newer Quantlib releases (i.e. 1.30 onwards)? It doesn't seem to have any effect when enabled, or am I mistaken? Thanks.

Comment: It's still there.  Where is it that you don't see the effect?

Comment: When pricing an irregular floating leg (1m freq with 3m libor index) with a timing/convexity adj. I would have expected to see a difference with the flag enabled/disabled but the fixings (effective rate) look the same in both cases.

Comment: btw when i recompile the quantlib libraries to enable/disable the flag i don't rebuild swig to update the python module. usually when editing the quantlib c++ code u don't have to update the python module. could that be the culprit?

Comment: Hmm, no, you have to recompile the python module.  You can skip that only if you're modifying code in a cpp file, but headers are included in the wrapper code.

Comment: understood. yep, that solved it. thanks.